# Generics (List) typing question

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I am trying to use a common technique to create objects from Xml. (Xml is legacy, so although there are already libraries to do this, it seemed faster to write this myself.)

I don't understand the compiler's complaint about the generic usage.  Code sample:

```
public void createObjects() {
  List<Object1> objectOnes = new ArrayList<Object1>();
  List<Object2> objectTwos = new ArrayList<Object2>();

  parseObjectsToList("XmlElement1", objectOnes);
  parseObjectsToList("XmlElement2", objectTwos);
}

private void parseObjectsToList(String xmlTag, List<? extends Object> targetList) {
   // read Xml and create object using reflection
   Object newObj = createObjectFromXml(xmlTag);
   targetList.add(newObj)  

/* compiler complains: "The method add(capture#2-of ? extends Object) in the type List<capture#2-of ? extends Object> is not applicable for the arguments (Object)" 
*/

/* If I change method signature to parseObjectsToList(String xmlTag, List targetList)
it works fine, but generates compiler warning about raw type */

}
```

Thanks for any enlightenment on the subject!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `List<Object>` will work, but you might want keep your more precisely typed `List<Object1>` and `List<Object2>` for type-safety elsewhere. In that case, you'll need to check the type of each object before adding it to the `List`.

```
private void parseObjectsToList(String tag, List<T> list, Class<? extends T> c) {
   // read Xml and create object using reflection
   Object newObj = createObjectFromXml(tag);
   list.add(c.cast(newObj))  ;
}
```

The `cast()` operation is a reflective equivalent to the static cast operator: `(T) newObj`

Using the altered method would look something like this:

```
parseObjectsToList("XmlElement1", objectOnes, Object1.class);
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem you are running into is that, with the bounded wildcard that you have defined, you will be unable to add any element to the collection.  From [this tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html):

> `List<? extends Shape >` is an example of a bounded wildcard. The ? stands for an unknown type, just like the wildcards we saw earlier. However, in this case, we know that this unknown type is in fact a subtype of Shape. (Note: It could be Shape itself, or some subclass; it need not literally extend Shape.) We say that Shape is the upper bound of the wildcard.
>
> There is, as usual, a price to be paid for the flexibility of using wildcards. **That price is that it is now illegal to write into shapes in the body of the method**

Answer (score 2):

All a wildcard type means is that the actual type parameter `T` of the `List` that you pass as the second argument to `parseObjectsToList` is going to be a subtype of `Object`.  It does NOT mean that the same `List` will be parameterized with different types.

So now you have a `List<T>` (called `targetList`) and you are trying to call `targetList.add(Object)`.  This is illegal because `Object` is not necessarily a subtype of `T`.

Because you are adding to the `List` rather than extracting elements from it, use `List<Object>` and make sure that's exactly what you pass in.

Comment: `List<?>` has the same problem as `List<? extends Object>`. The wildcard means that the `List` has a type parameter, but it's unknown. Therefore, adding any elements to it could "pollute" the collection with elements of the wrong type.

Comment: Thanks for help - the <?> wildcard usage limitation is a lot clearer now.  I ended up doing: 
parseObjectToConfig(MESSAGE_CONSUMER_TAG, auxiliaryMessageConsumers);  // this is List<MessageConsumer> type

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private boolean parseObjectToConfig(String xmlTagName, List storage) {  ... }

Since the type of the list is unimportant at this point. The List<Object> didn't work, because compiler didn't like passing strongly typed lists to the method as List<Object>.  

The solution: 
 ... parseObjectsToList(String tag, List<T> list, Class<? extends T> c)  looks good!

Answer (score 1):

Think about what you are asking the compiler to do:

1. Given a list of "something that is a subtype of `Object`
2. Let me insert an `Object` into it

This doesn't make sense.  Suppose your list is a list of `Integer`.  Suppose that `createObjectFromXml` returns a `String`.  It wouldn't make sense to allow inserting a `String` into a list typed for `Integers`.

So, your options are either to make your List a `List<Object>` or to find some way to make `createObjectFromXml` return a specific type, that you can then tie to the type of your list.